Adhesive for attaching wood handle to metal
I'd like to permanently attach a wooden knob with a hole drilled to fit a metal rod as shown in this photo:

I tried silicone since it often forms a decent bond with just about anything but as there is no oxygen once the knob is in place, it refused to set up.
I also read elsewhere about possibly using contact cement, but I don't have much experience with contact cement and I am unsure if the bond would form too aggressively when I try to slide the knob into place, and prevent it from sliding all the way down.

Epoxy would be the canonical solution. If the fit is tight enough, a gel superglue may work

I've routinely attached wooden handles to metal rods.  I use epoxy.  I usually cut threads on a small portion of the metal rod.
Now if you want something extremely serious, there is an epoxy sold, even at home centers, that is intended to anchor studs into concrete, including those that hold down lifts you might see in automotive repair shops.  That epoxy would be extreme overkill for this instance.

Epoxy is the first adhesive to pop into my alleged mind with this question. Superglues tend to get brittle as they age and may more easily crack free from the metal. It's probably a good idea to scuff up the steel inside the wood, to give a better grip to the epoxy. One last consideration is that long-duration-cure types of epoxy will provide stronger bonding and in this application, five minute cure isn't really needed, is it?

Thanks! It just so happens I have some Gorilla 5 minute cure epoxy sitting in a drawer that I got for something years ago but never used. I know next to nothing about expoy so this will be a first encounter but I'll give it a try.

Read the label on your epoxy for clean up.  I think it was acetone or rubbing alcohol that cleans up fingers and drips.  Rarely can I apply epoxy without getting a bit on my fingers.

If you can't cut threads into the rod, at least file some circumferential grooves or something for the epoxy to bite.
